# setContent to InfoWindow of Google maps in ionic native

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, ionic-native

I would like to be able to have button in InfoWindow. I have tried to use title instead of content as below:

```
map.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe((e) => {
  let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
    position: e,
    title:"<button>Test</button",
    draggable: true
  };
  map.addMarker(markerOptions).then((marker: Marker) => {
    marker.showInfoWindow()
  });
});
```

When I tested it in my android device, it just show the String '<button>Test</button>' without any button. Is there any missing or any other functions to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Content, not title

```
  let markerOptions: InfoWindowOptions = {
    position: e,
    content:"<button>Test</button",
    draggable: true
  };
```

Comment: It does not work. As in the document of ionic native of google maps here [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/#Marker) , it does not have content for marker options.

Comment: Its InfoWindowOptions and not MarkerOptions

Comment: I have tried to put InfoWindowOptions, but it does not work. Anyway, in the [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/), there is no InfoWindowOptions. Thanks.